# error in cmake opencv: Parse error in command line argument: -D

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

it is a while I am trying to install opencv but each time I have some problems with the configuration of cmake.
this is the cmake I am trying to use:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON 
-D WITH_XINE=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON 
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON
-D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON 
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/username/main-env/opencv3.0 
-D WITH_GTK = ON -D MATLAB_ROOT_DIR=/home/MATLAB/R2015a ..
```

,but got this error

```
Parse error in command line argument: -D
Should be: VAR:type=value
CMake Error: No cmake script provided.
CMake Error: Problem processing arguments. Aborting.
```

P.S. I want to put it in main-env folder which is the virtual environment folder to avoid any problems with system files and less struggling with various errors encountered in previous times. not sure possible maybe it is totally wrong. please let me know if you have some knowledge about it.

Comment: You wrote `-D WITH_GTK = ON`; it is supposed to be `-D WITH_GTK=ON` (without the extra spaces).

Comment: @AndreasUnterweger thank you very much I didn't notice that. solved

Comment: @AndreasUnterweger's comment should be the accepted answer IMO, it is much more clear what the problem is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the all terms should be separated by -D and shouldn't be any attached terms with -D